# Getting error while using fixture.detectChanges(); using jasmine in angular

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to use jasmine to check if the click event is fired. The method that is called using click event uses event emitter. I have tried the following code , but somehow i get error "Failed: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'mobileNum' of undefined" when i use fixture.detectChanges();

```
it('trigget next button click', async(() => {

    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginForm1Component);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    debugger;
    spyOn(component.validateLoginEvent, 'emit').and.callThrough();

    const nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const button = nativeElement.querySelector('#loginBtn');

    button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.templateService.validFormFlag).toBe(false);
    component.validateUserRequest = {
        mobileNum: 'XXXXXXXX',

    };
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.validateLoginEvent.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();

}));

<form class="transfer-form marginTop120" id="loginForm" #declarativeForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group" id="email" class="email">
        <label for="mobileNumber" class="col-form-label col-form-label-lg" id="textformat">
            {{ 'LOGIN.ENTER_YOUR_MOBILE_NUMBER' | translate }}&nbsp;<span class="labelHint">q12333</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="mobileNumber" placeholder="05XXXXXXXX" [(ngModel)]="validateUserRequest.mobileNum" only-number maxlength="10" />
    </div>  // getting error here
   <div style="transform:scale(0.7);transform-origin:0;">
    <re-captcha [(ngModel)]="declarativeFormCaptchaValue" name="captcha" (resolved)="resolved($event)" required></re-captcha>
</div>
    <div class="button-holder loginStep1">
       
        <a class="button btn-md btn-blue button-step-1 fa-pull-right new-button" id="loginBtn" href="javascript:void(0);" validateLoginDirective [ngClass]="{'disabled': !declarativeFormCaptchaValue && globalService.properties.CAPTCHA_ENABLE }" (click)="validate(this.templateService.validFormFlag)">
            {{ 'SHARED.NEXT' | translate }}
        </a>    // this is next click
    </div>
</form>


export class LoginForm1Component implements OnInit {
  @Input() validateUserRequest: ValidateUserRequest;
  @Output() validateLoginEvent = new EventEmitter();
  public declarativeFormCaptchaValue: any;

  constructor(
    public router: Router,
    public globalService: GlobalService,
    public templateService: TemplateService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  validate(isValid: boolean) {
    if (isValid) {
      this.validateLoginEvent.emit();
    }
  }

  resolved(captchaResponse: string) {
    console.log(`Resolved captcha with response: ${captchaResponse}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: It means that you haven't defined `validateUserRequest`

Comment: Assign the value to ```component.validateUserRequest = { mobileNum: 'xxxxxxx' }``` before ```fixture.detectChanges()``` called.

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy after adding the above loc, i am getting error, Expected spy emit to have been called.

Comment: you can check the variable while you clicking on the button ```isValid``` is true or false.

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy How to do this?

Comment: add ```console.log``` in your ```validate(isValid)``` function or remove ```if``` Validation in that function

Comment: isValid is true, do we need to check this variable value as well in the spec test case?

Comment: yes @Nancy......

Comment: Even after adding the code to check variable value, i am facing this  error.Expected spy emit to have been called.Have edited my original code with latest code.

Answer (score 0):

In the template, you are using validateUserRequest

`[(ngModel)]="validateUserRequest.mobileNum"`

Do you initialize that validateUserRequest in the ts file?

Initiliaze validateUserRequest and then try :)

Comment: Yes, in ts file, its initialized,   @Input() validateUserRequest: ValidateUserRequest; For more reference, I have added my ts code as well to the original question